# What I need to do with solr/development/data/index/somefiles by git?

Tags: git

Every time, when I add this files to .gitignore,later I get this files again like new files. I think server don't see this files after adding to .gitignore and create new index files. How to use git in this case? How to work with this files in git? What shall I do? Maybe I need to add this files to stash all?

**.gitignore:**

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files for more about ignoring files.
#
# If you find yourself ignoring temporary files generated by your text editor
# or operating system, you probably want to add a global ignore instead:
#   git config --global core.excludesfile '~/.gitignore_global'

# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
!/log/.keep
/tmp

public/images/coffee.png
public/images/Ruby.png
public/images/css.png
public/images/java.png
public/images/php.png
public/images/pithon.jpeg
public/images/up.png
public/system/photos/images/000/000/004/original/images.jpeg
public/system/photos/images/000/000/003/original/CDMbA57p.png
public/system/photos/images/000/000/002/original/CDMbA57p.png
public/system/photos/images/000/000/001/original/CDMbA57p.png
public/system/photos/images/000/000/008/original/bigstock-red-paper-clip-27302498.jpg
public/system/photos/images/000/000/006/original/paper-clip-clip-art-KingopKrT.jpeg
public/system/photos/images/000/000/005/original/paperclip.jpg
public/system/photos/images/000/000/007/original/images.jpeg
public/system/photos/images/000/000/009/original/pictures-9.jpg
public/system/photos/images/000/000/010/original/paperclip.jpg
public/system/songs/audios/000/000/002/original/Nathan_Goshen_–_Thinking_About_It_(KVR_Remix)_.mp3
public/system/songs/audios/000/000/001/original/thinking_about_you.mp3
public/system/songs/audios/000/000/004/original/Nathan_Goshen_–_Thinking_About_It_(KVR_Remix)_.mp3
public/system/photos/images/000/000/001/original/no-ff-5.png
solr/default/data/index/segments_1
solr/default/data/index/write.lock
solr/development/data/index/_4.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_4.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_4.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_4.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_4.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_4.si
solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/segments_1
solr/development/data/index/segments_9
solr/development/data/index/write.lock
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000004
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000005
solr/test/data/index/segments_1
solr/test/data/index/write.lock
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000007
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000006
solr/development/data/index/_1.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_1.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_1.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_1.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_1_1.liv
solr/test/data/index/write.lock
solr/test/data/index/segments_1
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000007
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000006
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000005
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000004
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000003
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000002
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000001
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000000
solr/development/data/index/segments_5
solr/development/data/index/write.lock
solr/development/data/index/segments_9
solr/development/data/index/segments_5
solr/development/data/index/segments_1
solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_4_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_4.si
solr/development/data/index/_4.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_4.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_4.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_4.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_4.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_2_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_2.si
solr/development/data/index/_2.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_2.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_2.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_2.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_2.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_1_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_1_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_1_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_1_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_1.si
solr/development/data/index/_1.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_1.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_1.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_1_1.liv
solr/development/data/index/_1.si
solr/development/data/index/_1.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_1.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_1.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_1.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_1.fdt
solr/default/data/index/write.lock
solr/default/data/index/segments_1
solr/development/data/index/segments_3
solr/development/data/index/_0_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_0_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_0_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_0_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_0.si
solr/development/data/index/_0.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_0.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_0.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_0.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_0.fdt
solr/development/data/index/segments_7
solr/pids/development/sunspot-solr-development.pid
public/20161205121500_remove_provider_from_users.rb
public/20161205121327_remove_uid_from_users.rb
config/secrets.yml

solr/development/data/index/segments_2
solr/development/data/index/segments_4
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000011
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000009
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000008
solr/development/data/index/segments_d
solr/development/data/index/_a_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_a_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_a_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_a_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_a.si
solr/development/data/index/_a.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_a.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_a.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_a.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_a.fdt
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000010
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000015
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000013
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000012
solr/development/data/index/segments_h
solr/development/data/index/_e_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_e_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_e_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_e_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_e.si
solr/development/data/index/_e.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_e.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_e.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_e.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_e.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_b_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_b_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_b_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_b_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_b.si
solr/development/data/index/_b.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_b.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_b.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_b.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_b.fdt
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000014
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000041
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000040
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000039
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000038
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000037
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000036
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000035
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000034
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000033
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000032
solr/development/data/index/segments_17
solr/development/data/index/_z_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_z_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_z_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_z_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_z.si
solr/development/data/index/_z.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_z.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_z.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_z.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_z.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_14_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_14_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_14_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_14_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_14.si
solr/development/data/index/_14.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_14.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_14.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_14.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_14.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_11_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_11_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_11_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_11_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_11.si
solr/development/data/index/_11.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_11.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_11.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_11.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_11.fdt
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000062
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000061
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000060
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000059
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000058
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000057
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000056
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000055
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000054
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000053
solr/development/data/index/segments_1s
solr/development/data/index/_1p_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_1p_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_1p_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_1p_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_1p.si
solr/development/data/index/_1p.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_1p.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_1p.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_1p.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_1p.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_1r.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_1r.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_1r.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_1r.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_1r.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_1r.si
solr/development/data/index/_1r_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_1r_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_1r_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_1r_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/segments_1u
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000063
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000064
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000067
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000066
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000065
solr/development/data/index/segments_1x
solr/development/data/index/_1u_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_1u_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_1u_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_1u_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_1u.si
solr/development/data/index/_1u.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_1u.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_1u.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_1u.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_1u.fdt
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000075
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000073
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000074
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000072
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000071
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000070
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000069
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000068
solr/development/data/index/segments_25
solr/development/data/index/_20_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_20_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_20_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_20_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_20.si
solr/development/data/index/_20.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_20.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_20.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_20.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_20.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_1z_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_1z_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_1z_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_1z_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_1z.si
solr/development/data/index/_1z.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_1z.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_1z.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_1z.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_1z.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_1x_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_1x_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_1x_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_1x_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_1x.si
solr/development/data/index/_1x.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_1x.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_1x.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_1x.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_1x.fdt
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000078
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000077
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000076
solr/development/data/index/segments_28
solr/development/data/index/_23_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_23_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_23_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_23_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_23.si
solr/development/data/index/_23.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_23.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_23.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_23.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_23.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_21_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_21_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_21_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_21_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_21.si
solr/development/data/index/_21.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_21.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_21.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_21.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_21.fdt
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000098
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000096
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000097
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000095
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000094
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000093
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000092
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000091
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000090
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000089
solr/development/data/index/segments_2s
solr/development/data/index/_29_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_29_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_29_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_29_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_29_3.liv
solr/development/data/index/_29.si
solr/development/data/index/_29.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_29.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_29.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_29.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_29.fdt
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000104
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000103
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000102
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000101
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000100
solr/development/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000000000099
solr/development/data/index/segments_2y
solr/development/data/index/_2i_Lucene50_0.tip
solr/development/data/index/_2i_Lucene50_0.tim
solr/development/data/index/_2i_Lucene50_0.pos
solr/development/data/index/_2i_Lucene50_0.doc
solr/development/data/index/_2i.si
solr/development/data/index/_2i.nvm
solr/development/data/index/_2i.nvd
solr/development/data/index/_2i.fnm
solr/development/data/index/_2i.fdx
solr/development/data/index/_2i.fdt
solr/development/data/index/_29_5.liv
```

Comment: show your gitignore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files under Solr's index directory and tlog is named sequentially and the naming will not be reused.

As long as you don't want to have your index in git (and you probably don't want that), you can add the complete data directory to `.gitignore`, instead of each file by itself:

```
# Solr indexed content
solr/development/data
```

Comment: I am new and only now I understand how .gitignor file works. Thanks.